# Generate XML in format <Field Name="TagName">value</Field>

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I need to generate XML file in following format:

`<Field Name="TagName">value</Field>`

I am using the *XmlTextWriter*. It works but closing tag looks like : `</Field Name="TagName">` and I would like it to be `</Field>`

Below my function to create node.

```
private static void createNode(string fieldName, string fieldValue, XmlTextWriter writer)
        {
           writer.WriteStartElement("Field Name="+"\"" + fieldName + "\"");
           writer.WriteString(fieldValue);
           writer.WriteEndElement();

        }
```

Can you tell me if there is any library for c# which allows me to generate the xml in the format I am expecting or should I modyfiy the XmlTextWriter? If so, how?

Comment: Are you sure you need to mess around with XmlTextWriter? This would probably be easier to just have a class and sierialize it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to add the attribute during the `WriteStartElement` call - use [`WriteAttributeString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter.writeattributestring?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_XmlWriter_WriteAttributeString_System_String_System_String_) separately:

```
       writer.WriteStartElement("Field");
       writer.WriteAttributeString("Name",fieldName);
       writer.WriteString(fieldValue);
       writer.WriteEndElement();
```